# Stationary distribution of identity matrix

Tags: probability, probability-theory, markov-chains

I am studying for quiz. I want to find stationary vector for $$\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1  & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}$$

I drew the markov picture and tried $x = xP$ but did not get a solution. Does it mean that the stationary distribution does not exist?

Comment: For clarification: was this a question you came up with for practice, or one someone else gave you? I ask only because it's not a great question to practice concepts like stationary distributions; the Markov picture is boring (it only has loops from vertices to themselves) and *every* vector is a stationary vector. This is because your matrix is the $3 \times 3$ identity matrix, and it is the only $3 \times 3$ matrix for which every vector is stationary.

Comment: You should’ve gotten an infinite number of solutions.

Answer (score 1):

Any vector $x$ satisfies the condition

$$
x = x P
$$

where $P$ is the identity matrix. The other conditions you need for $x$ to be a stationary distribution are

- It must have non-negative entries
- The sum of its components must be $1$